# Is the project's name available in the Unit Output Directory Option using Delphi XE2?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I would like to create an common Option Set to set basic settings for the many projects we have, and I would like to direct each project's dcus to separate folder.

I would like to set the "Unit output directory" to something like Build\dcu\$(Platform)\$(Config)\$(ProjectName)

Now there is no such variable as $(ProjectName). Is there somethine else?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is the reason for having $(ProjectName) as well. The first part Build\dcu\$(Platform)\$(Config)\ I understand.

Comment: seems there is no way to use `$(OTUPUTNAME)` and `$(PROJECTNAME)` from build events in DCUs path... but you can do somethong else.. if your build dcus path is (for example) "C:\build\dcu\" (define it as variable in common options like `$(BUILD_PATH)`); then you can set DCUs path to ".\dcu\", after that in pre-build events you can link dcu to your real path like `mklink /d dcu ($BUILD_PATH)\($platform)\$(config)\$(OUTPUTNAME)\` (Vista/7 and NTFS), and in post-build event remove this symlink

Comment: Hi Clint,
I would like to reference a single Option Set with multiple projects. The project use different compiler defines, so I want to separate the dcus.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem.
Try `\$(Platform)\$(Config)\$(MSBuildProjectName)`
That does the job for me.

Comment: I'm using Delphi XE7 and I get a `[Fatal Error] Can't load package MyPackage.bpl...`. [Is there a solution working on Delphi XE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461383/how-to-get-the-current-project-name-in-delphi-directories-settings)?