# Delphi compiler options

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, parameters

When compiling a Delphi app you have some params to use in the config $(Config)\$(Platform) places the compiled file in Release\Win32 
Are there any param that gives me the programname as stated in the DPR file (which is also the name of the exe file)

Just to make it a bit more clear what I want:
I want all my compiled exe to be put in a Folder called C:_Delphi_Compiled\Projectname\Config\Platform  (Using the project I mention further down it will be C:_Delphi_Compiled\GUIDmaker\Release\Win32)
This will give me a bit more control over my projects exe files and DCU files

Comment: You know the name of your project. Hard code it into the output directory.

Comment: I know that but then I have to remember doing that every time I create a new project. If I could use the params, I could save that as standard and not have to worry about that anymore. 
I am not getting any younger :-)

Comment: @David one may have few DPR files having distinct feature sets (free, trial, lite, pro,...) and having other settings in sync

Answer (score 2):

`$EXENAME` is the name your project's output file (`Project1.exe` for applications, `Project1.dll` for libraries, etc.)

`$PROJECTFILENAME` is the name of your DPR file

Comment: +1 good find. Surely the syntax is `$(EXENAME)` and `$(PROJECTFILENAME)`. I could not find documentation of them. Also, I tried to use `$(EXENAME)` in a post-build script and that variable was empty.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I found the list in the `Configure Tools` menu

Comment: I have tried them both and neither of them can be used for this.
They don't create any folders as does $(Config) and $(Platform)

Comment: @OZ8HP No they don't create any folder. Why should they? They are the name of your project and your output file.

Comment: Because I use them as params for the output directory

Comment: @OZ8HP I believe you can use them as parameters to pass to build tools

Comment: @iMan You didn't state these requirements in the question

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9597461/978342
    `\$(Platform)\$(Config)\$(MSBuildProjectName)` this will give you what you need.

Comment: Just one problem when using $(MSBuildProjectName) - the compiler won't run the output when you try by F9

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by won't run. But if you require the full path with extention you might want to try: $(OutputPath). If you need the extention only try: $(OutputExt)

Comment: When I use $(MSBuildProjectName) as part of the output name I can build the project OK, but if I press F9 to run it from the IDE I get an error like  >>Could not find program, 'C:\_Delphi_Compiled\%MSBuildProjectName%\GUIDmaker.exe'<<
But the 'funny' part of it is that the file exists in a folder in this case named C:\_Delphi_Compiled\GUIDmaker

I an running Delphi XE not that I think that matters

Comment: If you set the binary output path to "c:\Delphi\Compiled\$(MSBuildProjectName)\$(Config)\$(Platform)" you should get what you want

Comment: I should do yes, but I get the error telling me that the file can't be found when pressing F9 to run my project from the IDE

Answer (score 0):

There's also `Application.ExeName`, though if this is called by a dll the name of the calling exe is returned rather than the name of the dll.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ExeName