# How to get the current project name in Delphi directories settings?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe7

In the project directory settings, I often need to use the project name, say `'MyProject'`, as part of the output paths.

[image]

I would prefer to avoid hardcoding the project name in the settings.

Is there a variable, like `$(Config)` and `$(Platform)`, to dynamically obtain the current project name (without extension)?

Comment: Why don't you use relative paths?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I want to place the output files outside the project folder

Comment: That makes versioning very difficult. Normally I'd view that step as a post build action.

Comment: Have you tried Application.ExeName property? It returns file name of the application's executable file including path. You can extract filename with ExtractFileName function then.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *$(SanitizedProjectName)* for this purpose. Be aware that the debugger might not support that.

Comment: On compiling I get a `[Fatal Error] Can't load package MyPackage.bpl...`. It seems that `$(SanitizedProjectName)` includes the extension?

Comment: I've also tried `$(MSBuildProjectName)` but it produces the same error

Comment: It's very strange because on compiling, it creates the `MyPackage` folder and creates the `MyPackage.bpl` file inside of the folder, but after doing that, it raises the error

Comment: The loader probably cannot resolve that variable. Is it _compiling_ or are you _installing_ the package?

Comment: It's on compiling, the package is new and it is not installed and is not required by other installed packages

Comment: I've tried running the IDE with the `r` param (`bds.exe -r`) but it still raises the same error

Comment: Well, obviously something is trying to load that package. A simple test with a brand new package doesn't show that error.